# DataGridView - Use DataPropertyName to show child element property

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Lets image that I have the following classes

```
public class Master
{
    public string MasterName = "Something";

    public List<Detail> details = new List<Detail>();
}

public class Detail 
{
    public string Foo = "Test";
}
```

And then I want to show the collection of Details objects in a DataGridView, using the code below

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
column.DataPropertyName = "Details.Foo";
column.HeaderText = "Foo header";

dgv.Columns.Add(column);
```

The column is shown in the grid, but without value

Comment: Are you sure DataPropertyName is what you want? It seems like you're looking for something more along the lines of Value. I suspect you're not working with ASP.Net, which is what I'm most familiar with, but I'd check the other properties of the DataGridViewTextBoxColumn to see if there's something else there that will give you what you need.

Comment: @Melanie I am using windows forms. I'll take a look into other properties

Comment: Also, when I use another object's property its fine, like: DataPropertyName = "MasterName"

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221207/datagridviewcolumn-datapropertyname-property

Comment: As stated by @JonPeterson in the link above, what I want to do is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221207/datagridviewcolumn-datapropertyname-property)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override ToString method in the entity child for example:

```
public class FormulariosENT {

    #region PROPERTIES

    public int IdFromulario { get; set; }
    public string DescripcionFormulario { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region PUBLIC METHODS
    public override string ToString() {

        return DescripcionFormulario;
    }
```

And later bind the entity child name.

Comment: What about EF generated class? I can't modify them

Comment: Then how can I make the DescripcionFormulario editable by the datagrid?

Comment: This falls short when you need 2 (or more) properties of the same object, or need to use it in different grids. Handy quick and dirty option, but not good for serious development.

Answer (score 16):

If you need to be more generic (i.e. using `DataPropertyName = "MyProp1.MyProp2.MyProp3"`) you can use this

```
private void Grid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewColumn column = Grid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex];
    if (column.DataPropertyName.Contains("."))
    {
        object data = Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
        string[] properties = column.DataPropertyName.Split('.');
        for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length && data != null; i++)
            data = data.GetType().GetProperty(properties[i]).GetValue(data);
        Grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to use many child elements like this:

```
class MyClass
{
   public int Id;
   public MyOtherClass OtherClass;
}

class MyOtherClass
{
   public string Name;
   public int Number;
}
```

How about:

**1st solution**
Set value for each cell in some event (mabye another one is better), manually, after setting datasource, for example:

```
private void dgv_CellFormatting( object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e )
{
   MyClass data = dgv.Rows[ e.RowIndex ].DataBoundItem as MyClass;

   dgv.Rows[ e.RowIndex ].Cells[ "colName" ].Value = data.OtherClass.Name;
   dgv.Rows[ e.RowIndex ].Cells[ "colNumber" ].Value = data.OtherClass.Number;
}
```

**2nd solution**
What about creating proper DataTable from the data and then just bind it?

I'd be thankful for any opinion ;-)

Comment: Good idea, and probably fast. MSDN warns that this function will be called quite often and lengthy processing should be avoided. Hence two improvements: (1) Only format the cell that is requested via parameter e. The function will be called once for every cell being formatted. (2) Instead of using strings for the columns, use e.ColumnIndex to access the cell

Answer (score 4):

Just do this:

Mask the property you want to get a childvalue from with [Browsable(false)] so it wont show up in the datagrid.
Then create a NEW property in your class that holds the child object which has only a "get" method showing the childproperty value:
For example:

```
[Browsable(false)] //Because we use the CreatorUsernameProperty to do this.
public virtual User Creator { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Creator")] //shows like this in the grid
public string CreatorUsername => Creator?.Username;
```

Answer (score 0):

where is your datasoure?  you must lead to source. that it will find it. 
you can do this

source :

1. :

   ```
   List<Detail> list = new List<Detail>();
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
        Detail d = new Detail();
        d.Foo = "test";
        list.Add(d);
   }

   this.dgv.DataSource = list;
   this.dgv.Columns[0].Visible = false;
   DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
   dgvc.HeaderText = "列标题";
   dgvc.DataPropertyName = "foo";
   this.dgv.Columns.Add(dgvc);
   ```
2. :

   ```
   public class Detail
   {
        private string foo;

        public string Foo
        {
            get { return foo; }
            set { foo = value; }
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: How to get this for a subtype?

Answer (score 0):

[bubi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35863096/312407) is great. I added a small tweak that lets the approach work if you're using [BindingListView](https://github.com/waynebloss/BindingListView).

Edit: this approach disables sorting on columns located via subproperty. Not sure how to fix this at the moment.

```
if (column.DataPropertyName.Contains("."))
{
    object data = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
    if (data is ICustomTypeDescriptor ictd) // support BindingListView
        data = ictd.GetPropertyOwner(null);
    string[] properties = column.DataPropertyName.Split('.');
    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length && data != null; i++)
    data = data.GetType().GetProperty(properties[i])?.GetValue(data);
    e.Value = data;
}
```