# how to make a property of a foreign table appear on datagridview using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I have two tables auto gen from my MySQL database

```
public partial class adviser
{
    public int adviserId { get; set; }
    public string employeeNo { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string middleName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> statId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> createdById { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> createdOn { get; set; }

    public virtual stat stat { get; set; }
    public virtual user user { get; set; }  
}

public partial class stat
{
    public stat()
    {
        this.advisers = new HashSet<adviser>();            
    }

    public int statId { get; set; }
    public string statName { get; set; }
    public string details { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<adviser> advisers { get; set; }  
}
```

then i have this method to get the collections of advisers

```
public List<adviser> GetList(AdviserParam p)
{
    List<adviser> items;
    using (VotingContext context = new VotingContext())
    {
        items = context.advisers.Include("stat").Where(x  =>
            (x.adviserId == p.AdviserId || p.AdviserId == 0) 
            && (x.employeeNo.Contains(p.EmployeeNo) || p.EmployeeNo == "") 
            && (x.lastName.Contains(p.LastName) || p.LastName == "") 
            && (x.firstName.Contains(p.FirstName) || p.FirstName == "") 
            && (x.middleName.Contains(p.MiddleName) || p.MiddleName == "") 
            // && (x.statId == 1)
            ).ToList();     
    }

    return items;
}
```

then I use these codes to put them into the data grid view (win form), I edited the columns so that it wont display the adviserId and statId properties.

```
ItemsGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
ItemsGridView.DataSource = vm.EntityList; // vm.EntityList is where I put the returned advisers from the GetList() method)
```

but the dgv doesn't display the statName (from stats table). How can I make it appear?

Comment: if you're trying to bind a column to something like "stat.statName" then the DataGridView does not automatically support child references. Your options would be to either: a) bind the grid to a POCO ViewModel which contains a flattened view of the data. b) Add a property in your "parent" to inspect the child value. (i.e. StatName in the Adviser that returns stat.statName) c) bind to "stat" and add a ToString() implementation that returns Name. d) use CellFormatting. (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046830/datagridview-use-datapropertyname-to-show-child-element-property)

Comment: Selecting a new anonymous type will fix your problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get value from **stat** object you can select an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) and include all the required properties.

I've shown a simple example to include statName and employeeNo.

```
var items = context.advisers.Where(x => x.adviserId == yourAdviserID)
        .Select(a=> new {name = a.stat.statName, employee=a.employeeNo}).ToList();
```

Now if you bind **items** to Datagridview you'll see only **name** and **employee** columns.

If you dont want to display advisorID and statID then just dont include them in your new anonymous type.