# winform datagridviewtextboxcolumn datapropertyname child

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I Need to display the child entity in a table.

```
// Entitys
public class Sp
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int IdDict { get; set; }
   public Dict Dict { get; set; }
}

public class Dict
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

How to bind?

```
var c = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    // How can I do?
    DataPropertyName = "Dict.Caption"  
}
```

The application is displaying an empty cell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221207/datagridviewcolumn-datapropertyname-property)

Answer (score 0):

Have done so. Works

```
// Entitys
public class Sp  
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdDict { get; set; }
    public Dict Dicts { get; set; }
    public DictCaption { get { return Dicts.Caption; } }
} 
public class Dict
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
.... 
dataGridView.DataSource = dbContext.Set<Sp>().ToList;
var c = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    DataPropertyName = "DictCaption"  
}
```